# Drawing 3d surfaces in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

How to draw 3d graphs in JavaFX using a mathematical equation,
basically 2 variable functions, for example: `z=2xy` and other 3D figures?
Is there any way to do it in JavaFX or do I need another Java library for that.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself already?

Answer (score 4):

As @Roland points out, JavaFX 3D API doesn't include other than the basic elements, like [`TriangleMesh`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html), which you can use to create complex shapes, like 3D graphs.

In fact, plotting 2D functions `f=f(x,y)` is be a very good use case for understanding how `TriangleMesh` works.

Basically you will need:

*A function*

The function can be expressed using built-in `Function` functional interface:

```
Function<Point2D,Number> function2D;
```

so for any pair of coordinates (x,y) it will return a value:

```
double value = function2D.apply(new Point2D(x,y)).doubleValue();
```

*Grid or range of coordinates*

If you think of a rectangular grid and a given number of the divisions, you will have a way to get all the plotting `(x,y)` points, and with the function, you will have the third coordinate `z` to generate the 3D points required for the mesh.

```
TriangleMesh triangleMesh = new TriangleMesh();
triangleMesh.getPoints().setAll(x0,y0,z0, x1,y1,z1, ...);
```

You will need to provide the texture coordinates if you want to have an image or a density map as a texture, or just an empty set of coordinates for now:

```
triangleMesh.getTexCoords().setAll(0,0);
```

Finally, you need to provide the faces, which are triangles. You just need to get the indices of the vertices for every triangle in your grid, like in this [sample](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com.es/2015/01/creating-and-texturing-javafx-3d-shapes.html), using 0 for the texture indices in this case:

[image: faces]

```
triangleMesh.getFaces().setAll(0,0,20,0,21,0,...);
```

And you will have your mesh, ready to be rendered in a scene.

**Third party libraries**

You can have a look at [FXyz](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz) library, where you will find [`SurfacePlotMesh`](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/shapes/primitives/SurfacePlotMesh.java), that will do exactly as described above, including texture coordinates. The FXyz [Sampler](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) is an application to visualize most of the possibilities on this library. This is a sample of a plotted function:

[image: FXyz]

For other 3D shapes, have a look to the rest of the 3D complex shapes in the library.

And you can have a look to [VRL Studio](http://vrl-studio.mihosoft.eu), which includes a great 3D function plotter, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a JavaFX demo application (embedded in swing) which can plot 3d points.
You can create/calculate some 3d points with your function and than just draw it. Check out the StarterFrame class, where the points are generated. More points means a more detailed plot. Maybe this helps you to write something on your own. Otherwise i would recommend a library.

https://github.com/adihubba/javafx-3d-surface-chart

[image: Gauss normal distribution]

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX doesn't have a built-in mechanism to draw 3d graphs. You have to use a 3rd party library.