# Surface chart in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, charts, surface

Is there a way to produce a surface chart in JavaFX? Seems like JavaFX supports only 2D-charts. I know there is Orson Charts but it is paid

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31760356/3956070)?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. But, honestly, I hoped to find much simpler API. Something like JFreeChart or JavaFX charts. I just need to display some data to give better understanding of it to user and I don't want to dive deep into all 3D stuff, it's not main purpose of my application. But it seems like I have to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a 3d / surface chart with JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073007/how-to-create-a-3d-surface-chart-with-javafx)